# An ANT script to sync local with a remote version

Tags: java, deployment, ant, build

Please, excuse my complete lack of experience with ANT.

I am looking for a script that basically compares the modification date of every .class file in a given local build, with that of its corresponding copy in a remote directory (server or sth). If a local file has recently been modifed, it just replaces the remote .class file with the local one.

I know that there are a lot of scripts for building war files and redeploying the whole application, and this is clearly what I don't want. Going through that every time for just a few lines of code being changed doesn't make any sense

Even if you can't point out a whole script, please give me some directions to look at. I know that ANT is pretty powerful so something like that should be a piece of cake, for even a newbie to write, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task does exactly that.